# Why signal interval is -T/2?

Tags: math, fourier

While going over some notes for the past year, I never really understood why many of the integrals for signals and systems, integrate over \$ [- \frac{T}{2},\frac{T}{2}]\$ rather than just \$[0,T]\$. (The same is can be true for \$ [-T,T]\$ vs \$[0,2T]\$ )

Why is that a common interval ?

Here is an example of what I mean.

[image]

Edit:
I corrected the internal from \$ [0, \frac{T}{2}]\$ to \$[0,T] \$. So you may see some answers talk about a range that wasn't in the question.

Comment: T is the signal repetition period. [0,/T/2] doesn't covers one full period, [-T,T] and [0,2T] covers two periods. [0,T] and [-T/2,T/2] are both one period interval, being more or less useful taken into account is signa l is odd or even.

Answer (score 5):

One simple reason : \$[-\frac{T}{2} , \frac{T}{2}]\$ cover one entier period of the signal while \$[0 , \frac{T}{2}]\$ cover only half a period.

But, I think your true question is : **Why \$[-\frac{T}{2} , \frac{T}{2}]\$ rather than \$[0 , T]\$?**

In both case, an entier period is cover. So? What is the difference?

It doesn't really matter since you will have the same result if you do the calculation.

- Using the \$[-\frac{T}{2} , \frac{T}{2}]\$ interval makes calculation easier. As you may notice, signal use to be periodic, that mean, the expression use to be like "\$cos(2πxT)\$". When "\$cos(2πxT)\$" is integrated between \$[-\frac{T}{2} , \frac{T}{2}]\$, "/2" get rid of "2*". This makes things a little easier.
- When a periodic signal is represented, most of the time (at least on exercice book), only one period is drawn with \$x = 0\$ as middle point. It is then logic to integrate from \$-\frac{T}{2}\$ to \$\frac{T}{2}\$.

[image: Periodic signal]

Comment: Ah. Yes. You caught my mistake too, I meant to say [0,T] and not T/2.